# check is variable is null before insert into mysql table

Tags: java, insert, null, pst

I update dates in mysql table. My problem is that some dates is null don't insert into table. I use this check but my problem is for type int

```
public void Salva(String query){
    int i = 1;
    try{
        con=Connessione.ConnessioneDB();
        pst= con.prepareStatement(query, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        if (anno != null){
            pst.setString(i, getAnno());
            i++;
            }
        if (numFormulari != null){
            pst.setString(i, getNumFormulari());
            i++;
        }
        if (dataFornulari != null){
            pst.setString(i, getDataFornulari());
            i++;
        }
        if (getIdClienti != null){
            pst.setInt(i, getIdClienti());
            i++;
        }
        if (idIva != null){
            pst.setString(i, getIdIva());
            i++;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Primitive type like `int` can't be null, you should try to use the class Integer

Answer (score 0):

As Hoffman said, primitive types, like integers, cannot be `null`. What you CAN do is come up with an invalid value (like -1, since I assume, your IDs cannot be negative). Modify the your methods to return an invalid ID if they can't get valid one and check for invalid id instead of `null`.

I assume you are checking the only `int` ID i see in the code. And in general.

Also, more of your code (for instance code for `getIdClienti()` method) and more details about your project might help us to find a better suited solution.